# ASP.NET Core returns serialisation of Task only on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some ASP.NET Core code that runs fine on my machine, but returns unexpected results when running on the server

```
    [HttpPost("DoSomething")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(MyObject myObject) 
    {
            
        var updatedObject = await SomeAsyncTask(myObject);
        return Ok(updatedObject);
    }

    public async Task<MyObject> SomeAsyncTask(MyObject myObject)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "url");

        var response = await SendRequest<ApiResponse>(req, myObject);

        return myObject;
    }
```

On my machine, the response is always the JSON of myObject,

```
//myObjectJson
{
    "property1":"some value",
    "property2":"some value"
}
```

However running on the server windows-latest in azure, I get myObject wrapped in a serialization of the task performing the work.

```
{
   "Result":{
      //myObjectJson
      "{
          "property1":"some value",
          "property2":"some value"
      }"
   },
   "Id":20,
   "Exception":null,
   "Status":5,
   "IsCanceled":false,
   "IsCompleted":true,
   "IsCompletedSuccessfully":true,
   "CreationOptions":0,
   "AsyncState":null,
   "IsFaulted":false
}
```

What's the reason for the variance and how can I ensure consistent returns?

Comment: Its really not clear which response you are getting in both situation, hows your `myObject` really looks like? The response you have added is it are you getting on server or on your local machine? Even not clear  what `someCondition` really is. and what object you are passing while calling this API. Could you provide some reproducible example so that it can be investigate?

Comment: Post your real SomeAsyncTask code.